# How to check result of malloc for nested struct? In C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I can allocate memory for pointer to `struct bmp_ptr` and I can check if the pointer is valid. But I need to allocate memory for `header` or `dib` member, how could I check that the `malloc()` was successful? I can `malloc()`, but using type cast means that the resulting pointer from `malloc()` would disappear. How could I declare the nested type?

```
header:
typedef struct BMP_DIB BITMAPINFOHEADER;
// BMP_DIB definition follows..

// BMP_FILE_struct definition follows:
    typedef struct BMP_FILE_struct {
      BMPHEADER header;
      BITMAPINFOHEADER dib;
    } BMPFILE;
```

main inside function:

```
BMPFILE * bmp_ptr;
bmp_ptr = malloc(sizeof(BMPFILE));
if (bmp_ptr == NULL) return NULL;
```

Comment: Exactly the same way as for whole struct?

Comment: When a given `malloc()` fails you should consider `free()`ing the previous successful `malloc()`s, and also IMHO, one line `if` statements are confusing in the long run, they don't improve your coding style, the make it worse.

Comment: Allocating the structure will allocate space for the members. You don't need to allocate them separately unless they are pointers.

Comment: "using type cast means that the resulting pointer from malloc would disappear." -- I don't understand, can you give some code example (the code given looks OK), I don't see what's the question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what pass after sizeof: `    bmp_ptr->header = malloc(sizeof(bmp_ptr->header));` this is not possible, so what type to pass there? How?

Comment: Did you read my comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Added after the comments]**

TL;DR - You don't need to allocate dynamic memory [or, check for the address is `NULL` or not] for compile time allocated variables. They will always have *defined* memory location and cannot be NULL.

As your `header` and `dib` are not pointer variables, you don't need to `malloc()` separately for them. `malloc()`-ing for `bmp_ptr` will allocate memory for them both.

---

*[Currently outdated]*

Point 1. You need not and please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Point 2. Anyways, `Cast`ing does not change the return *value*, it is related to the *type*.

> for head or dib member, how could I check that the malloc was successful?

you need to check against `NULL` for `bmp_ptr->header`.

- if `malloc()` is successful in allocating memory you'll have a non-`NULL` value.
- if `malloc()` fails, it'll return `NULL`.

Same goes for `dib` also.

<sup>**Note : Considering `header` and `dib` are pointer type variables.** If they are not pointers, then no need to allocate memory using `malloc()`.</sup>

Comment: I cannot do this: `bmp_ptr->header = malloc(sizeof(bmp_ptr->header));` so how do get the type for sizeof?

Comment: @user1141649: You probably want something along `bmp_ptr->header = malloc(sizeof *bmp_ptr->header);`, but the question isn't really clear.

Comment: @user1141649 You can do `bmp_ptr->header = malloc(sizeof(BMPHEADER));` but there's a lot of ___if___ 's. is `header` a pointer?

Comment: It is a struct: `typedef struct BMP_HEADER BMPHEADER`

Comment: @user1141649 that changes the complete scenario. Wait for my updated answer.